# Converting LinkedHashSet to ArrayList or just using ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, linkedhashset

Consider the following code:

```
final Set<String> allPaths = new HashSet<String>();
for (final String path: paths) {
        allPaths.add(path);
}
final MyData d = new MyData(new ArrayList<String>(allPaths));
```

`MyData` is some class I should not touch. It should get an `ArrayList` as an argument. Before this day, we used that way because we didn't care about the order, that is why we used `Set` (so there will not be duplicated). But now, I would like to keep the order of the elements, so after some research, I found out that I can use the data structure `LinkedHashSet`  in order to do so. So I did:

```
final LinkedHashSet<String> allPaths = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
for (final String path: paths) {
        allPaths .add(path);
}
final MyData d = new MyData(new ArrayList<String>(allPaths));
```

Problem is, I'm not sure how to convert `LinkedHashSet` to `ArrayList`. Also, I thought of using `ArrayList` instead of `LinkedHashSet` so I won't have to convert it, but I'll have to iterate over the array (`O(n)`).

What good, clean and effiect way should I use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Set to List without creating new List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892360/convert-set-to-list-without-creating-new-list)

Comment: Change `MyData` to use a `Collection`. Why was it hardcoded to use an `ArrayList` in the first place?

Comment: What is wrong with the way you are doing it? There should not be a difference in the creation of the `ArrayList` between using a `LinkedHashSet` and using any other `Set`, except that it will use the proper iteration order.

Comment: what's the problem with what you're doing right now? I mean, creating a list fro ma set is basically what you did and this is fine. what does it have to do with `O(n)`? I don't get this point.

Comment: ...and I wonder what `paths` is in your code? Is that a `List` or `Set`?

Comment: ...or is `paths` even an array?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I (partly) agree with you, but since he says "MyData is some class I should not touch.", changing the constructors signature seems to be no option. I only partly agree, because if the constructor requires **ordered** data, a general `Collection` argument doesn't express that.

Comment: @DorianGray I made it a comment, and now I'm going to ask: **why** "MyData is some class I should not touch."? A `List` (or `Iterable`) would be better then hardcoding an `ArrayList`. But since we can't **see** `MyData` I remain unconvinced as to its' inviolability.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I guess he uses some 3rd party library

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use the `public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)` method, on the arrayList, it accepts any `Collection`.

You have your `LinkedHashSet`:

```
final LinkedHashSet<String> allPaths = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
for (final String path: paths) {
        allPaths .add(path);
}
```

and then do (you can use this even if `mylist` is not empty):

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
mylist.addAll(allPaths);
```

or for even a simpler approach:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>(allPaths);
```

Comment: does `new ArrayList<String>(<???>)`  know to handle with a collection (like `LinkedHashSet`)? If so, will my way still work?

Comment: @TTaJTa4 yes, that is the whole point of the Collection interface. It is an abstract idea, that has many implementations, but it is basically the same thing, a **collection of things**. Java uses Collection, instead of hard coded implementations (like ArrayList for example), to be able to swap from one implementation to another - just like in your case, when you want to use LinkedHashSet instead of HashSet, without the need to re-write the method/class you are passing the argument into.

Comment: `addAll` is merely an extra over what the OP already did. There is no need to use it, it can be used the way it was originally.

Comment: @RealSkeptic you call use the `addAll` method even if the list is not empty, in case he needs it, as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I'm wondering what's different in your answer from what he already does in his question?!

Comment: It is not, he merely asked if it is the way to go because he wasn’t sure of how to convert the collections , I showed him a couple of options

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you just convert your `paths` to an `LinkedHashSet` like that (assuming that `paths` is a Collection?

```
final MyData d = new MyData(new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(paths)));
```

In case `paths` is an array, you can use `Arrays.asList(paths)` inside the conversion above

Answer (score 0):

```
@TTaJTa4 you can use the code below as an example. Both ways are fine.



import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class ConvertLinkedHashSetToArrayList
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Set<String> testStrings = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    testStrings.add("String 1");
    testStrings.add("String 2");
    testStrings.add("String 3");
    testStrings.add("String 4");
    testStrings.add("String 5");

    System.out.println("** Printing LinkedHashSet: " + testStrings);
    ArrayList<String> linkedHashSetToArrayList1 = new ArrayList<>(testStrings);
    System.out.println("** Printing linkedHashSetToArrayList1:" + 
    linkedHashSetToArrayList1);

    ArrayList<String> linkedHashSetToArrayList2 = new ArrayList<>();
    linkedHashSetToArrayList2.addAll(testStrings);
    System.out.println("** Printing linkedHashSetToArrayList2:" + 
    linkedHashSetToArrayList2);
  }
}
```

Results are like:

```
** Printing LinkedHashSet: [String 1, String 2, String 3, String 4, String 5]
** Printing linkedHashSetToArrayList1:[String 1, String 2, String 3, String 4, String 5]
** Printing linkedHashSetToArrayList2:[String 1, String 2, String 3, String 4, String 5]
```

Follow the GitHub link for the full java project:
[GitHub example](https://github.com/DIL8654/JavaExamples)

Answer (score 0):

If `paths` is a collection you can get an array list no duplicates:

`ArrayList<String> p = paths.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));`

If `paths` is an array:

`ArrayList<String> p = Stream.of(paths).distinct().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));`